# Bash, one directory, run script from a script, extraordinary error

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to test my script by running it inside another script. I googled up some solutions and implemented them (btw - both scripts are in one directory) but I keep getting a following error.

> ./tr_znaki.sh: 13: ./tr_znaki.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this script is about to run another script"
a=ab
b=AB
echo "$a" 
echo "$b" 
sh ./tr_znaki.sh "$a" "$b"
```

Any ideas?

znaki_tr.sh

```
first_two="$1 $2" #zapisuje dwia pierwsze znaki do wspolnej zmiennej
a="$1";b="$2" #rozdziela znaki
split1=$(echo $a | fold -w 1) #rozdziela a na litery i wypisuje
split2=$(echo $b | fold -w 1) #rozdziela a na litery i wypisuje
arr1=($split1) #zapisanie stringu do tablicy
arr2=($split2) #zapisanie stringu do tablicy

shift #usuwa pierwszy argument
shift #usuwa drugi argument


size1=${#arr1[@]} #zapisanie rozmiaru arr1 do zmiennej
size2=${#arr2[@]} #zapisanie rozmiaru arr2 do zmiennej

# nieskończona pętla pozwalająca na ciągłe wpisywanie tekstu do translacji, przerywana standardowo ctrl + c
while true
do 
    read tekst #zmienna, do której wpisywany jest przez użytkownika tekst
    mod=$tekst #zapisanie wpisanego tekstu do zmiennej
    for (( i=0; i<${size1}; i++ ));  
    do
        mod=${mod//[${arr1[i]}]/${arr2[i]}} #nowa zmienna z zamianą którejś z wartości w arr na odpowiadającą wartość w arr2
    done
    echo $mod #wypisanie zmienionego tekstu
    #sleep 1 #czeka sekundę

done
```

Comment: OK, so what does tr_znaki.sh look like?

Comment: What is the Line 13 of `./tr_znaki.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend add your script to execute in a variable:
Try something like this:

```
      #!/bin/bash
      tr_znakiScript="/Directory/From/My/Script/tr_znaki.sh"
      echo "this script is about to run another script"
      a=ab
      b=AB
      echo "$a" 
      echo "$b"
     . $tr_znakiScript "$a" "$b"
```

remove the sh at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're running the second script with `sh` rather than `bash`. Arrays are a `bash` extension, so

```
ize1=${#arr1[@]} #zapisanie rozmiaru arr1 do zmiennej
```

can't be used with `sh`. Run the script with:

```
bash ./tr_znaki.sh "$a" "$b"
```

Or change `tr_znaki.sh` to begin with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and run it with

```
./tr_znaki.sh "$a" "$b"
```

Comment: I must have deleted it because on top of the file I had some comments for  myself, but the line #!/bin/bash is present in the tr_znaki.sh file.

Comment: The shebang line only matters if you run the script as a command, it has no effect if you run `sh` or `bash` explicitly with the script as an argument.